# How to find Net Force with constant velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, differentiation

Does having a constant velocity always make the acceleration equal zero?

For example: A 5 kg ball is moving at constant velocity of 15 m/s. What is the net force on the ball?

If the formula is $F_{net}=ma$ and acceleration is zero because the velocity is constant
Does this mean the net force is zero?

Comment: Try arguing using Newton's first law. It will be conceptually clearer that way because it defines motion.

Comment: -1 Not clear why you think the reasoning in your last paragraph might be  wrong.

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration).

Answer (score 1):

**Acceleration is defined as the rate of change of Velocity.**

When you say that the velocity is constant, so it doesn't change, by the definition of acceleration it is zero as you say.

This also implies that the net force is zero as a force is required to produce an acceleration. Note that we say 'net force' we mean the resultant of all the forces.